# Not all response headers are showing up on swagger UI (openapi 3.0.0)

Tags: docker, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I brought up the swagger UI (openapi 3.0.0) using the spec.yaml and the latest swagger ui docker image (swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest) on my local machine. I am hitting an API endpoint using the swagger UI, for some reason I am NOT able to see all the response headers, where as when I hit the same endpoint on P ostman I can see all the response headers.

For example, Let's assume I see below response headers on Postman

response-header1, 
response-header2, 
response-header3, 
response-header4, 
response-header5, 
response-header6, 
response-header7, 
response-header8

I see only these response headers on swagger UI

response-header1, 
response-header2, 
response-header3, 
response-header4

Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Note : I came across some github issue threads / even stack overflow query threads with more or less similar defect scenario and those have been closed with resolution saying the bug has been fixed. but if that is really fixed, I am just wondering why this is happening on latest docker image?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a CORS issue - see https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3340#issuecomment-313550973 and https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4576#issuecomment-390783413

Comment: @Helen - Thanks for sharing these threads. This indeed helped me!